# Rmarkdown failure while merging dataframes

Tags: r, merge, r-markdown

I have these code in a .R file working:

```
KnowledgeBaseDfPOC <- read_csv("C:/Users/ivanm/Desktop/Master/5. Data Driven Security/DL_vulnerabilities_abtes2vm_20191217.csv", skip = 3)
KDB_dfPOC <- KnowledgeBaseDfPOC[,c("QID", "Category", "Modified", "Published", "CVSS Base", "CVE ID")]
#View(KDB_dfPOC)

#Eliminar aquellos que no tengan valor CVSS
KDB_dfPOC_clean <- filter(KDB_dfPOC, KDB_dfPOC$`CVSS Base` != '\'-')
#View(KDB_dfPOC_clean)

#Juntamos los 2 DataFrame para poder relacionar datos
dfPOC <- merge(test, KDB_dfPOC_clean, by ="QID")
```

but when I put it in a .Rmd file i got the following error when trying to do the function:

```
dfPOC <- merge(test, KDB_dfPOC_clean, by ="QID")
```

The error is:

> Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify uniquely valid columns

Comment: This problem is not related to Rmarkdown it is related to merging data in general. Before merging make sure of the column names you are merging and that their name exist only once in each table. Also sometimes this error occurs when joining a dataframe to data table. It will be best if you could share structure of your sample data and a reproducible example.

Comment: @NaremanDarwish In my case test=data frame, KDB_dfPOC=tbl_df and KDB_dfPOC_clean=tbl_df

Comment: Just forgot to import the library(dplyr), now works

Comment: Another and more recent approach is to use the left_join() function from the tidyverse. Or similars, see: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html